# Show that $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n I(x-x_n)$ defines a bounded function on $\mathbb{R}$ that is continuous except, possibly, at the $x_n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

Define $I(x)=0$ $x\le 0$ and $I(x)=1$ $x>1$. Given sequences $(x_n)$ and $(c_n)$ in $\mathbb{R}$, with $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |c_n| < \infty$, show that $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n I(x-x_n)$ defines a bounded function on $\mathbb{R}$ that is continuous except, possibly, at the $x_n$

I has been trying to prove that the function is continuous. The problem is when I take the term $|f(x) - f(y)|$ to make it less the $\epsilon$. Could you please show me how to prove this problem.

Comment: The important thing is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |c_n| < \infty$.  So $\sum_{n=N}^\infty |c_n| < \infty$ goes to $0$ as $N \to \infty$.  In your $\epsilon, \delta$ proof that $f$ is continuous at a certain point $x$, you can concentrate on only finitely many terms, and use this to estimate the rest.

Comment: I will try to use your notation, hope to be able to prove it. Thanks.

Comment: The problem is that, $|f(x) - f(y)| \le |\sum_{n=k}^{n=L} |c_n|$. The right hand side is a fixed number? how could it be go to zero?

Comment: Let $x$ be a real value not equal to any $x_n$.  Let $\epsilon > 0$.  Choose $N$ so large that $\sum_{j=N+1}^\infty |c_i| < \epsilon/2$.  For any $n \in \{1,\dots,N\}$ the function $c_nI(x-x_n)$ is continuous at $x$.  Choose $\delta_n$ so small that $|x-y| < \delta_n \Longrightarrow |c_nI(x-x_n) - c_nI(y-x_n)| < \epsilon/(2N)$.  Let $\delta = \min\{\delta_1,\dots,\delta_N\}$.  Then $|x-y| < \delta \Longrightarrow |f(x)-f(y)| < \epsilon$.

Comment: OHHH, thank you very much. I thought it was just one $x_n$, the author did not mention that for every $n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x\not= x_n,\,\,\, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. So we need to show that $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n I(x-x_n)$ is continuous for every $x$ that located between any two points of the sequence $x_n$. Since the step function is continuous on every point $x \not x_n$, because;

For each $x \in (x_{n-1},x_{n})$ or $x \in (x_n, x_{n+1})$, where $n \in \mathbb{N}$, Let $\epsilon >0$, choose $\delta_0 = x_n -x_{n-1} >0$ and $\delta_1 = x_{n+1}- x_n >0$ such that

if $|x-y| < \delta_0$ then $|I(x-x_n) - I(y-x_n) =|0-0|=0 <\epsilon$.
and
if $|x-y| < \delta_1$ then $|I(x-x_n) - I(y-x_n) =|1-1| <\epsilon$.

Since the function $I(x-x_n)$ is continuous for any $x \not=x_n$, then $ c_nI(x-x_n)$ is continuous too (means there is $\delta_n$ for every $n$).

Now, doing the steps, Mr. @GEdgar showed in his comments.

Choose  $1<N \in \mathbb{N}$, so large such that $\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty} |c_n| \le \frac{\epsilon}{2}.$ Since (As we showed) $c_n I(x -x_n)$ is continuous on any $x \not= x_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. consequently, it is continuous on all $x \not = x_n,\,\,\, n\in \{ 1,...,N\}$. Choose $\delta_n$ so small such that

if $|x-y|< \delta_n$ then $|c_n I(x -x_n) - c_n I (y-x_n)| < \frac{\epsilon}{2 N}$.

let $\delta_n = \min \{ \delta_1,...,\delta_N \}$, so

if $|x-y| < \delta$ then

$|f(x)-f(y)|= |\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n I(x-x_n) - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n I(y-x_n)| $
$\le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |c_n I(x-x_n) c_n I(y-x_n)| $

$\le \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{\epsilon}{2 N} + \sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty} |c_n|$
$< \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2}= \epsilon.$

Comment: Thanks @The Mathematician, the clarification is perfect.